# A Windows' Ctrl+Z equivalent for OSX

Tags: keyboard, windows, switching

On many operating systems if you want to **undo** something you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I tried this on Mac OS X and it does not work. What is the suitable equivalent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> check Edit menu if you are unsure if the shortcut is available for a program or a scenario.

On a side note, <kbd>Command</kbd> works as the default shortcut key on Mac OS X where Windows' default modifier key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

This holds for Copy, Paste, Open, etc...

Comment: How do you make those cool key boxes?!

Comment: Check out this post by @dori on advanced formatting - http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193/keyboard-icons-terminology

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, many Windows <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>xxx</kbd> shortcuts are changed to <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>xxx</kbd>.

If you are a new switcher from Windows to Mac, check out the following switcher guide. Full of useful tips!

http://lifehacker.com/224674/hack-attack-a-guide-for-switching-to-a-mac

Comment: RE: ".. On a Mac, many Windows CTRL-xxx shortcuts are changed to CMD-xxx." - interesting history about this, when the 1984 Mac came out (with the world's first mass consumer distributed GUI OS), it was Apple that came up with all the "CMD Z, CMD C, CMD X, etc" short cut keys.  When Microsoft followed with Windows a few years later, it was Microsoft that copied all those shortcut keys and used CTRL key instead (since they didn't have a dedicated CMD Apple key on their DOS PC style keyboards).

Comment: I didn't know that! Interesting piece of history! :-)

Comment: In addition, the Mac OS was the first OS to establish the same command keys system-wide, to be adopted by all applications. Before Mac OS (in MS-DOS, etc.) every application had its own different command or function keys for Cut, Copy, Paste, Undo, Print, etc. So you had to learn different key commands for each and every application. When Microsoft developed Windows, they deliberatly copied the Mac system-wide approach.